# How to print this matrix on the console? - javacode

Tags: java, arrays

I need to print a matrix (I will add it at the end), but I need to print in with a gap in the middle, between 3rd and 4th columns, without changing the matrix variables.

What is the safest way to do it?

Is it better if I just print it in arrays with rows?

-If I make a mistake, I'm really sorry, I'm new to this :c

```
    char[] vcp = { 'V', 'C', 'P' };
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
            System.out.print("[" + vcp[c] + "]");
        }
        System.out.print("\n"); 

    int[][] matrix = new int[7][6];
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    System.out.print("["+matrix[i][j]+"]");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
```

Comment: would please be specific or provide some screenshot what you actually want to print?

Comment: I need to print something like the two 7*3 matrices. A big 7*6 matrix, divided in half. http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/sitio/images/cursosCupi2/apo1/ejemplos/n3_avion/Descripcion_archivos/image002.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the inner for loop, the one that uses j, just add

```
if (j == 2) { //third row, so we add a space
    System.out.print("        ");
}
```

I'm assuming that you want the output to look like

```
[a][b][c]        [d][e][f]

[a2][b2][c2]         [d2][e2][f2]
```

and so on.